# Mail composer working on iPad but no on iPhone in a Universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i've a problem with universal app on iOS iPhone4s/5 iPad, using a 3 different Storyboards, but with same class file .h .m for all application.

I create a button share with a popUp view and woking very well, when i tap on mail button iside the popUp view on the iPad working and present mail composer, but the same stuff in storyboard, with the same class on iPhone 4/5 open a mail level under the popup.

here coding using to send email:

```
- (IBAction)mailCompose:(id)sender {

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            [mail setSubject:@"Try MyRadioRed Now"];
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];

            [mail setToRecipients:toRecipients];
            NSString *emailBody = @"MyHTML text";

            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lockScreen.png"];
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
            [mail addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"myImge"];

            [mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
            mail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
            [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
}
```

On iPad loading correct the popup view and when tap on email button, load the Mail Composer over the popup view

[image: and this is a screen about what happen on iPad]

[image: Mail layer load correct]

On iPhone loading correct the popupView, but when tap on email button, mail compose load under the popupview:

[image]

[image]

Is very strange because I'am not change the code on class and the object on the storyboards, I have to copy and paste storyborad obj with the same setting and using only one class reference for all.

Have idea what happen? how to solve this issue?

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the position of the layers in your View Controller in Storyboard are the same?

Comment: Yes is exactly clone in every 3 storyboard iPad iPhone5 and iphone 4s or less

Answer (score -1):

`NS log` the presentation of the mail composer and check if its being called on the iPhone, are you testing this in simulator, device  or both?

If as you say the code is the same for all devices Check that you have email actually set up on your devices or you wont get presentation of the composer

Comment: Yes testing on simulator and devices, the NSLog is correct on the both, but inexplicably load the mail view under the popup only on iPhone. i Check the email settings and is all ok and working T_T

Comment: Ok I think I mis understood the question before, cant you dismiss the pop over in your `mailCompose` method or set to hidden?

Comment: On iPad can dismiss first the MailView and after if tap on blur the popup is dismiss perfectly, on iphone after load mailview under the popup if i tap on blur dismiss all popup and mailview, and if I reload popup the FB, TW, and Mail not working, but the output have no error -.-"